# sage syntax A.<x>

Tags: python, python-3.x, sage

in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) i can create a `PolynomialRing` over a field in the variable `x` like this:

```
A.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(2))
```

as shown in the [doc](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html).

my question here is purely about the syntax: what is `A.<x>`? in plain python this would be invalid syntax (right?)? and is there an associated `__something__` function that is called? or what is happening here? how is all of that an assignment to `A` (and to `x`)?

disassembling gives:

```
sage: from dis import dis
sage: def f():
....:     A.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(2))
....:     return A
....: 
sage: dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (PolynomialRing)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (GF)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (Integer)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('names')
             21 LOAD_CONST               5 (('x',))
             24 CALL_FUNCTION          257
             27 STORE_FAST               0 (A)
             30 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
             33 LOAD_ATTR                3 (_first_ngens)
             36 LOAD_CONST               4 (1)
             39 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             42 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          1
             45 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  3          48 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
             51 RETURN_VALUE
```

do the brackets call `_first_ngens`?

Comment: "in plain python this would be invalid syntax (right?)" => indeed. Sage is "based on python" but it's obviously not Python anymore.

Comment: Well, to be more precise, any valid Python statement is still valid Sage (I think?) but some additional statements which are *not* valid Python are preparsed. So think Python + syntactic sugar + tons of math.  See also my answer.

Comment: It is not the case that any valid Python statement is still valid Sage, at least not with the same meaning. For example, `^` means bitwise XOR in Python but exponentiation in Sage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an example of the syntax you need](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrKEotSCwqTtVQctSzqbBTsFUIyM-pzMvPzUzMCcrMS9dwd9Mw0tRU0gQAI70M6w==&lang=sage):

```
sage: preparse("A.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(2))")
"A = PolynomialRing(GF(Integer(2)), names=('x',)); (x,) = A._first_ngens(1)"
```

To elaborate, Sage builds in a preparser that takes invalid Python input that makes sense mathematically and gives valid Python. Actually, it is there a lot even when you don't think it is:

```
sage: preparse("2+2")
'Integer(2)+Integer(2)'
```

so that the arithmetic is in Sage arbitrary-precision `Integer`s, not Python `int`s.  The most famous example is probably

```
sage: preparse("f(x)=x^2")
'__tmp__=var("x"); f = symbolic_expression(x**Integer(2)).function(x)'
```

which looks a bit crazy but enables us to use "normal" math notation for defining symbolic functions, which are however not `def` Python functions in the same way.

(Finally, as to why that syntax works in your original example, apparently the history is that this is also Magma's syntax.)

Comment: For the cognoscenti, yes, even the caret `^` is preparsed as `**`!  Because bitwise xor is not usually what we want.